# What is the purpose of each of these code lines?

Tags: java

What is the purpose of each of the following code lines?

```
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));

    JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;

    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
    System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: Note that this code almost certainly has a resource leak, because the `FileReader` isn't closed.

Comment: Just a little nit-picking here: we can’t tell you the purpose. We might be able to tell you what the code lines do, but whether that was also the purpose, only the writer of the lines can tell. And to find out what they do, you may as well run them yourself. One by line in your debugger if you wish.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking a question here you are supposed to search and research. Search includes reading the documentation of Java and of the methods (including constructors) called in your snippet. Research includes running the code and seeing what happens. Next, in your question report what you found out and what you are still missing. That will make for a good Stack Overflow question and for precise answers to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a form of representing objects using java script. 
Think of

- **First** line as as reading it as plain text
- **Second** line is converting it into a json object.
- **Third** line as extracting the necessary properties of the object from the created json object.